# query builder, one to many where many is empty

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I have an entity Category, and this category has a recursive relationship with itself where each category can be a parent to several other categories. The relationship looks like this:

```
  /**
 * @var parent
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE") 
 */
private $parent;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent")

 */
private $children;
```

I need to make a query builder query that selects all categories that are either children(have a parent) Or the categories that have no parent and also have no children (in other words all categories except the parents that have children) I can't seem to be able to do it. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need next DQL query:

```
$query = 'SELECT c FROM AcmeBundle:Category c LEFT JOIN c.parent p LEFT JOIN c.children ch WHERE p IS NOT NULL OR (ch IS NULL AND p IS NULL)';
```

If you need QueryBuilder sequence for this query you can use next code:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $qb
    ->select('c')
    ->from('AcmeBundle:Category', 'c')
    ->leftJoin('c.parent', 'p')
    ->leftJoin('c.children', 'ch')
    ->where($qb->expr()->orX(
        $qb->expr()->isNotNull('p'),
        $qb->expr()->andX(
            $qb->expr()->isNull('ch'),
            $qb->expr()->isNull('p'),
        )
    ))
    ->getQuery();
```

Comment: I solved it by witing an sql query and rewriting my forms and my crud controllers(a whole mess) so it is done. But out of curiosity I would like to see what the query builder would have looked like. If I could do the query builder I would have been able to pass it directly in the form.

Comment: After becoming older and wiser I realize that your answer is correct as well :)

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov I can't do the querybuilder version of this DQL, could you add it, please? Besides, it would make the answer so much better, since it is what the question is actually asking for. :)

Comment: It's something like this:      
  $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

        $qb->select('c', 'cc')
                ->from('BackendNewsBundle:Category', 'c')
                ->leftJoin("c.parent", "p")
                ->leftJoin("c.children", "cc")
                ->where('p is null')
                ->orderBy('c.'.$order[0], $order[1]);

        return $qb;

Comment: @xDaizu, I added code you requested.
**JoeYahchouchi**, thanks for your comment as I forget about **xDaizu** request.